# installing an existing R packages on Linux server

Tags: linux

Please explain how to install the following package on the Linux server.
([R package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ada/index.html))
R is installed in /usr/bin/.
I'm not understanding the documentation I'm finding.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using

```
install.packages("ada", lib = "/usr/lib64/R/library", dependencies = T)
```